# Having trouble displaying an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey guys I'm having some trouble with my code. I'm trying to loop through this array but whenever I do, my program show up blank in FireFox. Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var finished1 = ["Firex";"Enrique";0;0];
      var finished2 = ["Detector";"Chris";0;0];
      var finished3 = ["Hpvv";"Diana";0;0];

      var info= new Array ( );
      info[0] = var info1 = ["Firex"; "Enrique"; 6; 20,000];
      info[1] = var info2 = ["Detector"; "Chris"; 7; 35,000];
      info[2] = var info3 = ["Hpvv"; "Diana"; 12; 10,000];
      info[3] = var info4 = ["Firex"; "Enrique"; 4; 25,000];
      info[4] = var info5 = ["Detector"; "Chris"; 3; 15,000];
      info[5] = var info6 = ["Hpvv"; "Diana"; 3; 30,000];
      info[6] = var info7 = ["Firex"; "Enrique"; 8; 10,000];
      info[7] = var info8 = ["Detector"; "Chris"; 5; 20,000];
      info[8] = var info9 = ["Hpvv"; "Diana"; 6; 15,000];
      info[9] = var info10 = ["Firex"; "Enrique"; 5; 25,000];
      info[10] = var info11 = ["Detector"; "Chris"; 6; 35,000];
      info[11] = var info12 = ["Hpvv"; "Diana"; 7; 35,000];
      info[12] = var info13 = ["Firex"; "Enrique"; 3 ; 40,000];
      info[13] = var info14 = ["Detector"; "Chris"; 9 ; 10,000];
      info[14] = var info15 = ["Hpvv"; "Diana"; 5 ; 15,000];

      for(i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          if (info[0][0] = info[i][0]) {
              finished1[3] = info[0][2] + info[i][2];
              finished1[3] = info[0][3] + info[i][3];
          }

          if (info[1][0] = info[i][0]) {
              finished2[3] = info[1][2] + info[i][2];
              finished2[3] = info[1][2] + info[i][3];
          }

          if (info[2][0] = info[i][0]) {
              finished3[3] = info[2][2] + info[i][2];
              finished3[3] = info[2][3] + info[i][3];
          }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this program I'm trying to take the information that is in the nested array. search and add up the third numbers and the fourth numbers if the array names match.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any statements that would result in human-visible output. Are you asking *generally* how to produce visible output? Also, your code has some serious problems: missing parentheses around `if` conditions, using assignment `=` instead of equality `==`, semicolons instead of commas in your array, right-hand-side `var` declarations, and no closing quote in `id="demo`. there are far too many problems here for a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You should have commas separating the element in the arrays, not semicolons.

Comment: it shouldn't even run with all those semicolons in the array filling statements.

Comment: You also have a number of case where you are hard-coding things where there is not need to do so.  I would suggest putting this code on codereview.stackexhcange.net to get some constructive feedback on ways you can improve your code.

Comment: ok guys thanks. i made all the changes and im going to take this down and put it on codereview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are trying to achieve.

```
var finished1 = ["Firex","Enrique",0,0];
var finished2 = ["Detector","Chris",0,0];
var finished3 = ["Hpvv","Diana",0,0];
var info = [];

info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 6, 20000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 7, 35000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 12, 10000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 4, 25000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 3, 15000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 3, 30000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 8, 10000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 5, 20000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 6, 15000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 5, 25000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 6, 35000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 7, 35000]);
info.push(["Firex", "Enrique", 3, 40000]);
info.push(["Detector", "Chris", 9, 10000]);
info.push(["Hpvv", "Diana", 5, 15000]);

info.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
  if(array[0][0] === array[index][0]) {
    finished1[3] = array[0][2] + array[index][2];
    finished1[3] = array[0][3] + array[index][3];
  }
  else if(info[1][0] === info[index][0]) {
    finished2[3] = array[1][2] + array[index][2];
    finished2[3] = array[1][2] + array[index][3];
  }
  else if(info[2][0] === info[index][0]) {
    finished3[3] = array[2][2] + array[index][2];
    finished3[3] = array[2][3] + array[index][3];
  }
});

console.log(finished1);
console.log(finished2);
console.log(finished3);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you are supposed to use semi colon in arrays I think you should use coma.